# Repeated measures ANOVA - different resutls for SPSS versus R

Tags: r, spss, anova

I am trying to run a repeated - measures ANOVA using R and compared it to the SPSS output and results differ a lot! Maybe I make a mistake somewhere, but I cannot figure it out
So some sample data:
id is the subject. Every subject makes one rating for three items (res_1, res_2 and res_3). I want to compare an overall effect of item.

```
id<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
res_1<-c(1,1,1,2,2,1)
res_2<-c(4,5,2,4,4,3)
res_3<-c(4,5,6,3,6,6)
## wide format for spss
table<-as.data.frame(cbind(id, res_1, res_2, res_3))
## reshape to long format
library(reshape2)
table<-melt(table, id.vars="id")
colnames(table)<-c("id", "item", "rating")
aov.out = aov(rating ~ item+ Error(id/item), data=table) 
summary(aov.out)
```

And here is my SPSS code (from wide format data)

```
GLM item_1 item_2 item_3
/WSFACTOR=factor1 3 Polynomial 
/METHOD=SSTYPE(3)
/PRINT=DESCRIPTIVE 
/CRITERIA=ALPHA(.05)
/WSDESIGN=factor1.
```

The results I get from
R: p value 0.0526  (error:within)
and SPSS: p value 0.003 (test of within subject effect)

Does anyone have a suggestion that may explain the difference?
If I do a non-parametric Friedmann test, I get the same results in SPSS and R.
Actually, when looking at my data, the summary(aov.out) is the same as SPSS's "test of within subjects contrast" (but I learned to look at the test of within subjects effect).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of stuff out there; I am a bit surprised that your google for 'spss versus R anova' did not bring you to links explaining about the difference in sums-of-squares between SPSS (type-III) and R (type-I) as well as difference in how contrasts are handled.

These are the top two results that I found:
http://myowelt.blogspot.ca/2008/05/obtaining-same-anova-results-in-r-as-in.html and 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40958/testing-anova-hypothesis-with-contrasts-in-r-and-spss

Comment: If I use "type 1" in Spss, this does not improve it much - Actually, I think there may be a mistake in my R code, as the effect should be highly significant, but in R it is not . In contrast, the Fridman test, which should have lower power, gives me highly significant results. Also, the differences in obtained p-values is not just from 0.45 to 0.48 (like in the examples I find online) but it is much much bigger...